# UrlRule. __construct и init() не вызываются

Tags: php, yii2, url, route, url-manager

Написал свое правило для urlManager'а.

При загрузке страницы вызывается метод parseRequest.

Но мне перед этим необходимо внедрить некоторые зависимости.
Пробую их внедрить и через __construct и через init(). Но они не вызываются. Прошу помощи.

Конфиг:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        [
            'class' => 'site\components\seo\SeoPageUrlRule',
            // DI через конструктор и init() не сканало, делаем так
            'managerClass' => 'common\components\seo\interfaces\ISeo'
        ]
    ],
],
```

Класс

```
<?php namespace site\components\seo;

use yii\web\UrlRuleInterface;
use yii\base\BaseObject;
use Yii;

class SeoPageUrlRule extends BaseObject implements UrlRuleInterface
{
    public $managerClass;
    protected $seo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'construct';
        die;
    }

    public function init()
    {
        echo 'init';
        die;
    }

    public function createUrl($manager, $route, $params)
    {
        /* */
    }

    public function parseRequest($manager, $request)
    {
        echo 'parse';
        die;
    }
}
```

На странице видим только `parse`

P.S. Я понимаю, что можно сделать доп. метод с нужной инициализацией и вызывать его внутри parseRequest и createUrl, но хотелось бы как-нибудь сделать это заранее.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        echo 'init';
        die;
    }
```

Comment: Попробовал. Результат тот же.